# Primary domain in vps has been deactivated

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration, vps

This is my scenario:

I have a vps with two domains (example1.com, example2.com). When I started with this vps I set `example1.com` as primary domain and the nameserver were configured with the pattern `ns1.example.com, ns2.example1.com`. The domains were brought in `name.com`.

Across the time, I usually only work whit the domain `example2.com`, for that reason I stopped to pay `example1.com` anual registration and just keep the example2.com. But, today my vps is unreacheable because the main domain was deactivated last ago 23th. I never imagined that it could affect my server.

So, I am so worried because I don't know if rebuild the vps is the solution here because I could lost my data. Can you take me to the right direction in order to recover my vps?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue. At the moment that the vps is unable to access via servername, you need to re-configutate it throws the ip. For example, if you hava CPanel installed just go to:

```
http://server-ip:2087 //if you have another port just change it
```

Of course you need to assign a new domain as primary, so, if you have one just go where you bought it and create the nameservers according to this domain and your server ips, usually are:

```
ns1.my-domain.com   //with ip xxx.xxx.xxx.001 
ns2.my-domain.com   //with ip xxx.xxx.xxx.002
```

Finally, in your Cpanel set the new nameservers created above, recycle the DNS server and wait some hours while your nameservers are propagated.